# adding new and close button to sortable grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

ive been strugling to make add and close button to work but i dont know how and ive been trying to look it up but i didnt find anything, can anyone please help or point me in the right direction
these are my code :

```js
$(function() {
  $('.sortable').sortable();
  $('.handles').sortable({
    handle: 'span'
  });
  $('.connected').sortable({
    connectWith: '.connected'
  });
  $('.exclude').sortable({
    items: ':not(.disabled)'
  });
});
```

```css
<style>h1,
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
}

#features {
  margin: auto;
  width: 460px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.connected,
.sortable,
.exclude,
.handles {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 510px;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.sortable.grid {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.connected li,
.sortable li,
.exclude li,
.handles li {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  background: #F6F6F6;
  font-family: "Tahoma";
  color: #1C94C4;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 22px;
}

.handles span {
  cursor: move;
}

li.disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.sortable.grid li {
  line-height: 80px;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

li.highlight {
  background: #FEE25F;
}

#connected {
  width: 440px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
}

.connected {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

.connected.no2 {
  float: right;
}

.status-closed {
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
  right: -25px;
}

.status-closed1 {
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
  right: -25px;
}

li.sortable-placeholder {
  border: 1px dashed #CCC;
  background: none;
}

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <h2>Grid</h2>
  <ul class="sortable grid">
    <li>Item 1<span class="status-closed1"><a href="#">X</a></span></li>
    <li>Item 2<span class="status-closed"><a href="#">X</a></span></li>
    <li>Item 3<span class="status-closed"><a href="#">X</a></span></li>
    <li>Item 4<span class="status-closed"><a href="#">X</a></span></li>
  </ul>
</section>
<br>
<div class="form-actions text-center">
  <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-info">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `.clone` and `.remove` combined with relative selectors to accomplish this.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.sortable').sortable();
  $('.handles').sortable({
    handle: 'span'
  });
  $('.connected').sortable({
    connectWith: '.connected'
  });
  $('.exclude').sortable({
    items: ':not(.disabled)'
  });
  $('.sortable').on("click", ".status-closed", function () {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
  });
  $('.add').on("click", function () {
    $(".sortable li:first").clone().appendTo(".sortable").show();
  });
});
```

```css
<style>h1,
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
}

#features {
  margin: auto;
  width: 460px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.connected,
.sortable,
.exclude,
.handles {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 510px;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.sortable.grid {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.connected li,
.sortable li,
.exclude li,
.handles li {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  background: #F6F6F6;
  font-family: "Tahoma";
  color: #1C94C4;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 22px;
}

.handles span {
  cursor: move;
}

li.disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.sortable.grid li {
  line-height: 80px;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

li.highlight {
  background: #FEE25F;
}

#connected {
  width: 440px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
}

.connected {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

.connected.no2 {
  float: right;
}

.status-closed {
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
  right: -25px;
}

.status-closed1 {
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
  right: -25px;
}

li.sortable-placeholder {
  border: 1px dashed #CCC;
  background: none;
}

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <h2>Grid</h2>
  <ul class="sortable grid">
    <li style="display:none">new<span class="status-closed"><a href="#">X</a></span></li>
    <li>Item 1<span class="status-closed"><a href="#">X</a></span></li>
    <li>Item 2<span class="status-closed"><a href="#">X</a></span></li>
    <li>Item 3<span class="status-closed"><a href="#">X</a></span></li>
    <li>Item 4<span class="status-closed"><a href="#">X</a></span></li>
  </ul>
</section>
<br>
<div class="form-actions text-center">
  <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn add btn-info">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping me sir, ive been looking for this :)